# HPA cannot read metric value (CPU utilization) on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm working on Google Kubernetes Engine on a single cluster.
The cluster automatically scales the number of nodes.
I have three created a Deployment and set up the auto-scaling policy using the website (Workloads -> Deployment -> Actions -> Auto-scaling), so not manually writing the YAML configuration.
Based on an official [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling?hl=it), I did not make any mistake.

> If you do not specify requests, you can autoscale based only on the
> absolute value of the resource's utilization, such as milliCPUs for
> CPU utilization.

The following is the full deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: student
  name: student
  namespace: ulibretto
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: student
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: student
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: CLUSTER_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: CLUSTER_HOST
                  name: shared-env-vars
            - name: BIND_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: BIND_HOST
                  name: shared-env-vars
            - name: TOKEN_TIMEOUT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: TOKEN_TIMEOUT
                  name: shared-env-vars
          image: gcr.io/ulibretto/github.com/ulibretto/studentservice
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: studentservice-1
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: student
  name: student-hpa-n3bp
  namespace: ulibretto
spec:
  maxReplicas: 100
  metrics:
    - resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
      type: Resource
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: student
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  labels:
    app: student
  name: student-ingress
  namespace: ulibretto
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.44.5.59
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: student
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

The problem is that the HPA does not see the metric (average CPU utilization), which is really strange (see image).
[HPA cannot read metric value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pSTJ.png)

What I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDITED**

You are right. You don't need to specify `namespace: ulibretto` in `scaleTargetRef:` as I mentioned earlier.

As you provided all YAMLs I was able to find proper root cause.

If you will check [GKE docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling?hl=it#create_the_example_deployment) you will find comment in code

```
    resources:
      # You must specify requests for CPU to autoscale
      # based on CPU utilization
      requests:
        cpu: "250m"
```

Your deployment didn't have specified `resource requests`. I've tried on this (I've removed some parts as I was not able to deploy your container and changed apiVersion in HPA):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: student
  name: student
  namespace: ulibretto
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: student
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: student
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: studentservice-1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "250m"
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: student
  name: student-hpa
  namespace: ulibretto
spec:
  maxReplicas: 100
  minReplicas: 1
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: student

$ kubectl get all -n ulibretto
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/student-6f797d5888-84xfq   1/1     Running   0          7s
pod/student-6f797d5888-b7ctq   1/1     Running   0          7s
pod/student-6f797d5888-fbtmd   1/1     Running   0          7s
NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/student   3/3     3            3           7s
NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/student-6f797d5888   3         3         3       7s
NAME                                              REFERENCE            TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/student-hpa   Deployment/student   <unknown>/80%   1         100       0          7s
```

After ~1-5 minutes you will receive some metrics.

```
$ kubectl get all -n ulibretto
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/student-6f797d5888-84xfq   1/1     Running   0          95s
pod/student-6f797d5888-b7ctq   1/1     Running   0          95s
pod/student-6f797d5888-fbtmd   1/1     Running   0          95s

NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/student   3/3     3            3           95s

NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/student-6f797d5888   3         3         3       95s

NAME                                              REFERENCE            TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/student-hpa   Deployment/student   0%/80%    1         100       3          95s
```

Same situation if you would like to create HPA using CLI:

```
$ kubectl autoscale deployment student -n ulibretto --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=100
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/student autoscaled

$ kubectl get hpa -n ulibretto
NAME      REFERENCE            TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
student   Deployment/student   <unknown>/50%   1         100       0          3s
```

And after a while you will receive `0%` instead of `<unknown>`

```
$ kubectl get all -n ulibretto
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/student-6f797d5888-84xfq   1/1     Running   0          4m4s
pod/student-6f797d5888-b7ctq   1/1     Running   0          4m4s
pod/student-6f797d5888-fbtmd   1/1     Running   0          4m4s
NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/student   3/3     3            3           4m5s
NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/student-6f797d5888   3         3         3       4m5s
NAME                                          REFERENCE            TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/student   Deployment/student   0%/50%    1         100       3          58s
```

Comment: See the first post: I've just updated the YAML config. I tried, but it seems that "namespace" is an unknown field both if I use "autoscaling/v1" (I used the example conf on the link you shared) and "autoscaling/v2beta1" (the version automatically created by the UI in GCloud). Anyway, to see the autoscaling I have to call " kubectl get hpa --namespace "ulibretto" ", since it is not present in the default namespace.

Comment: You, you are right. It was my mistake. I will edit this answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Well, GKE docs also says that: https://imgur.com/a/5kmA2vk . That's why I didn't write the request of the deployment (also because I'm not able to estimate it, I'm a newbie as it comes to K8S ). I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: You saved me. Thank you very much for the time spent helping me. 

Comment: Small addition to answer: if your pod contains more than one container - **all of them** should have resources/request settings. Just faced an issue.