# GKE: HPA cannot read metric value

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am trying to add a horizontal pod autoscale in my pod, but it is not working as expected, I had gone through the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling) and it says to add "resources.requests" in deployment and it should work but it is not working. It is able to identify the CPU but not the memory. Can someone point out what is I am missing here

**Standard GKE version: 1.24.11-gke.1000**

I tried with `apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2` but using this it was unable to ready both CPU and memory, and when I am using `autoscaling/v2` it able to ready CPU but not memory this is for `kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler`

this is my deployment definition file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deploy-orders
  namespace: sandbox
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/change-cause: "image updated to v__IMG_VERSION__"
  labels:
    app: deploy-orders
    tier: backend

spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: po-orders
      namespace: sandbox
      labels:
        app: po-orders
        tier: backend

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args:
        - --listener_port=8081
        - --backend=http://127.0.0.1:4000
        - --service=sandbox.endpoints.project-name.cloud.goog
        - --rollout_strategy=managed
        - --healthz=/healthz
        - --service_control_network_fail_policy=close
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8081
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      - name: container-orders
        image: my:image:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTP
            path: /live
            port: 4000
            httpHeaders:
            - name: X-Readness
              value: "yes"
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTP
            path: /live
            port: 4000
            httpHeaders:
            - name: X-Liveness
              value: "yes"
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
        # env var
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: secret-orders
          - configMapRef:
              name: cm-orders

        imagePullPolicy: Always
        # CPU and Resource
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
      serviceAccountName: ksa-sandbox

  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  minReadySeconds: 30

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: po-orders
      tier: backend
```

and this is my hpa definition file.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa-orders
  namespace: sandbox
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: deploy-orders
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 60
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 60
```

Here is the screenshot from GKE
[image]

screenshot from GKE of metrics-server
[image]

Please Note: I had already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62752352/5019802) and the solution provided I am already using it.

Comment: Hi @SaiChandraGadde: apologies for delay in response, I did checked your answer on next day only but some how I forget to reply.

Answer (score 0):

The error occur mainly due to metrics-server crushing or unresponsive, try bellow steps to resolve your issue:

1.Check if metrics-servers have the OOM (Out of Memory) event.

`Go to the GKE Console page⇒ open the “Workload” tab, search by “metrics-server”, click on deployment name On the deployment page click on the pod name`. Restarts count more than 0 already indicator of container being killed/errored.

If yes, The modification in metrics-server-config configmap is permanent. Increase memoryPerNode in metrics-server-config until there are no OOM events, follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/bare-metal/latest/how-to/log-monitoring#metrics_server).

2.If cannot see an OOM event, check if metrics-servers have high CPU OR/AND Memory utilization, if yes increase in the memory as the previous step.

3.If metrics-server is stuck in the "Unschedulable" state due to too big resource requests, create a NodePool with one node big enough to host a scaled metrics-server pod.

4.Check if metrics-servers have a problem with the konnectivity-agent on a public cluster, you can find it in the logs.

```
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io failed with: failing or missing response from https://10.60.0.4:10250/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Get "https://10.60.0.4:10250/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1": No agent available
```

If yes, restart the metrics-server and konnectivity-agent.

5. Check if metrics-server have problem scrapping metrics due to missing/misconfigured firewall rule, you can find the error similar to `error connecting to typha endpoint error connecting to typha endpoint (2 of 2) 10.0.0.55:5473 connID=0x0 error=dial tcp 10.0.0.55:5473: i/o timeout type="node-status"`

If yes, add a firewall rule for allowing traffic between nodes with the priority higher than the "Deny"(if any) to allow node-to-node communication, follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#cluster-fws).

Try the above steps and let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Hi, I did checked "metrics-server" it is working as expected, even I checked the logs there was no sign or errors. Also I have added a screenshot for the same in my above question.

Comment: Try running this query and let me know if you get any warnings: ```resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name="cluster name"
jsonPayload.source.component="horizontal-pod-autoscaler"
jsonPayload.involvedObject.name="priceline"
jsonPayload.reason="FailedGetResourceMetric"
--"priceline"```

Comment: This are no logs showing with matching labels, I tried with 4-5 combinations and I checked from last 45 days logs. By adding project_id with your given query, also I tried by `--"priceline"` removing this because it usage in not know to me.

Comment: Can you scrape metrics from nodes that no longer exist and check if the node count is spiky in the cluster.

Comment: Using  `kubectl get hpa -A | grep "" -c` can you give how many hpa's are you running or can you check how many HPAs on the server are created.